# Exercise B.5.(c) of Hindry and Silverman's Diophantine Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to do the following exercise:

Let $V$ be the projective line and $D$ is the point at infinity.
Suppose $f,g$ are morphisms from $V$ to $V$ with degree greater than $1$.
Show that $f$ and $g$ are commutative if and only if the canonical height
on $V$ relative to $D,f$ and the one relative to $D,g$ are same.

One direction is clear, namely if $f$ and $g$ are commutative, then the 
corresponding canonical height are same. But I have no idea how to prove the other direction. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards